# django-rest-framework: Rendering both HTML and JSON with the same ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django==1.10.5` and `djangorestframework==3.5.3`.

I have a few `ModelViewSet`s that handle JSON API requests properly. Now, I'd like to use `TemplateRenderer` to add HTML rendering to those same `ModelViewSet`s. I started with the `list` endpoint, and created a simple template that lists the available objects. I implemented the `get_template_names` to return the template I created.

Accessing that endpoint through the browser works fine when there are **no** objects to list, so everything related to setting up HTML renderers alongside APIs seems to work.However, when tere are objects to return the same endpoint fails with the following error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length XX; 2 is required
```

Where `XX` is the number of attributes the object has.

[This](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#varying-behaviour-by-media-type) documentation section suggests the view function should act slightly differently when returning an HTML `Response` object, but I assume this is done by DRF's builtin views when necessary, so I don't think that's the issue.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359077/context-aware-browsable-api-rendering-in-django-rest) stackoverflow Q/A also looks relevant but I'm not quite sure it's the right solution to my problem.

How can I make my `ModelViewSet`s work with both HTML and JSON renderers?
Thanks!

Comment: I now understand doing this is not as trivial as I initially thought. I ended up implementing my own `list` method in my `ViewSet`s that checks the `request.accepted_renderer.format`

Answer (score 2):

DRF has a brief explanation of how to do this in [their documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#varying-behaviour-by-media-type).

I think you'd do something like this...

On the client side, tell your endpoint what type of response you want:

```js
fetch(yourAPIUrl, {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
      // or 'Accept': 'text/html'
    }
  })
```

In your view, just check that and act accordingly:

```py
class FlexibleAPIView(APIView):
    """
    API view that can render either JSON or HTML.
    """
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Things.objects.all()

        # If client wants HTML, give them HTML.
        if request.accepted_renderer.format == 'html':
            return Response({'things': queryset}, template_name='example.html')

        # Otherwise, the client likely wants JSON so serialize the data.
        serializer = ThingSerializer(instance=queryset)
        data = serializer.data
        return Response(data)
```